# Eclipse Color Theme preview option is not working

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, spring-tool-suite

`Eclipse Color Theme` preview option is not working. I am using Spring Tool Suite latest version i.e. 3.8. It is just showing their home page instead of showing how the font style will be.

[See the snapshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utn51.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the color themes bug. 
Color Theme Preview doesn't display properly in Preferences #250
https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-color-theme/issues/250